# Yii2. Kartik datecontrol. Not initializes the datecontrol module

Tags: php, yii2, yii-extensions, yii2-basic-app, yii-modules

I tried to use [yii2-datecontrol](https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-datecontrol) module, but it not initializes. How to fix it?

Here is my `web.php`

```
'modules'    => [
        ...
        'datecontrol' => [
            'class'          => 'kartik\datecontrol\Module',
            'widgetSettings' => [

                'displaySettings' => [
                    kartik\datecontrol\Module::FORMAT_DATE     => 'dd-MM-yyyy',
                    kartik\datecontrol\Module::FORMAT_TIME     => 'hh:mm:ss a',
                    kartik\datecontrol\Module::FORMAT_DATETIME => 'dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss a',
                ],

                // format settings for saving each date attribute (PHP format example)
                'saveSettings'    => [
                    kartik\datecontrol\Module::FORMAT_DATE     => 'php:U', // saves as unix timestamp
                    kartik\datecontrol\Module::FORMAT_TIME     => 'php:H:i:s',
                    kartik\datecontrol\Module::FORMAT_DATETIME => 'php:Y-m-d H:i:s',
                ],

            ]
        ], 
        ...
    ],
```

Here is my modules, as you can see, the rest is objects, but `datecontrol` is an array.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It initializes, when it's being called at least once.